# Negating params in a Spring controller's RequestMapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller

Hi,

I've got two methods in my controller and I'm trying to get one method to fire if a parameter is a certain value and the other method if the parameter is not that value.  My "not" method is firing when the param equals the certain value.

According to (my understanding of) [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params%28%29) I'm writing the expression correctly.  Here are the signatures of the two methods:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/doit", params= {"output=grouped", "display!=1"})
public @ResponseBody HashMap<String, Object> doSomething(
@RequestParam("text") String text,
@RequestParam("display") String display)
{
  // this method runs if display=1 but why?
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/doit", params= {"output=grouped", "display=1"})
public @ResponseBody HashMap<String, Object> doSomethingElse(
@RequestParam("text") String text)
{
  // this method is not being called when display=1...why not?
}
```

I have Spring debug logging enabled and I see where Spring converts the parameter to a RequestParam String with value '1'.  In the very next line, though, it decides to map it to the wrong method.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not your fault: it is a Bug [SPR-8059](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8059). At the moment it is fixed in Version 3.1M2 and [svn Trunk rev 4408](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-framework/trunk/org.springframework.web.servlet/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/ServletAnnotationMappingUtils.java?r2=4408&r1=3484).

A workaround would be not to use `!=` in `@RequestMapping`. Instead you have to do it with an `if` by hand:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/doit", params= {"output=grouped")
public @ResponseBody HashMap<String, Object> acceptAll(
   @RequestParam("text") String text,
   @RequestParam("display") String display) {
  if("1".equals(display) {
      return doSomethingElse(text);
  } else {
      return doSomething(text,display);
  }
}
```